# Can a void function have pass by value parameters?

Tags: c++

I am a new C++ programmer. I am creating a calculator, and I have a problem with my `void printAnswer()` function. Whenever I call the function and I type in the parameter (which is a `double` variable), the function name always turns into a variable identifier. When I compile, it says

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State  
Error (active)  E0070   incomplete type is not allowed  Calculator  C:\Users\jk\Downloads\Coding Stuff\Calculator\Calculator.cpp    17  
Error   C2182   'printAnswer': illegal use of type 'void'   Calculator  C:\Users\jk\Downloads\Coding Stuff\Calculator\Calculator.cpp    17  
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data    Calculator  C:\Users\jk\Downloads\Coding Stuff\Calculator\Calculator.cpp    17
```

This is my header file.

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR_H

#define CALCULATOR_H

void calculator();
double getValue1(double);
double getValue2(double);
std::string getOperation(std::string);
double calculation(double, double, std::string);
void printAnswer(double);

#endif
```

This is my main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Calculator.h"

int main()
{
    double a{};
    double b{};
    double x{ getValue1(a) };
    std::string calculatorOperation{};
    std::string operation{ getOperation(calculatorOperation) };
    double y{ getValue2(b) };
    double answer{ calculation( x, y, operation ) };
    void printAnswer(answer);
   /*
    *   if (answer == 99999999999999999.999)
    *        std::cout << "Sorry. The desired operation does not exist or you have misspelled 
somthing.\n";
    *    else
    *        std::cout << "The answer is " << answer << ".\n";
    *
    *    return 0;
    */

}

double getValue1(double x)
{
    std::cout << "Please type your first number and press enter.\n";
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
}

double getValue2(double y)
{
    std::cout << "Please type your second number and press enter.\n";
    std::cin >> y;
    return y;
}

std::string getOperation(std::string operation)
{
    std::cout << "Please type in the desired operation in all undercase and press enter.\n";
    std::cin >> operation;
    return operation;
}

double calculation(double x, double y, std::string operation)
{
    if (operation == "addition")
        return x + y;
    else if (operation == "subtraction")
        return x - y;
    else if (operation == "multiplication")
        return x * y;
    else if (operation == "division")
        return x / y;
    else
        return 99999999999999999.999;
}

void printAnswer(double answer)
{
    if (answer == 99999999999999999.999)
        std::cout << "Sorry. The desired operation does not exist or you have misspelled somthing.\n";
    else
        std::cout << "The answer is " << answer << ".\n";
}
```

Comment: ***Can a void function have pass by value parameters?*** Yes of course.

Comment: What is with this bizarre number, `99999999999999999.999`? Don't use "magic numbers" like this. They cause unbelievable numbers of problems. Floating point already has you covered: `return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()` from `#include <limits>`. The NaN (Not a Number) principle in floating point is well-specified already.

Comment: `void printAnswer(answer);` --> `printAnswer(answer);` if you want to call the function.

Comment: `void printAnswer(answer);` is not a correct declaration of a function. With the `void` the compiler expects you are declaring a function not calling one.

Comment: As a general rule you should not be declaring functions inside a function.

Comment: You should also be declaring variables like `double a = 0.0` instead of `double a{}`. The constructor-style is best used with objects or arrays.

Comment: Why does `getOperation` take a string as an argument? It doesn't need one, you can just return a local variable.

Comment: Side note: Not far form the Error List Tab you'll find the Output Tab. Error list's job is to give a quick overview and it's intended to look pretty on a GUI. As a result it A) leaves out some information and B) looks like crap when converted to text. Output Tab shows you everything, and sometimes the extra information contains the details you need to know to solve the problem quickly. And sometimes the full build output overloads the brain buffer. But even if you can't understand the sprawling text, it pastes into Stack Overflow questions really nicely.

Answer (score 4):

In your `main` function, you have this line:

```
void printAnswer(answer);
```

Here the compiler thinks that you are trying to declare a `void` variable named `printAnswer` which is constructed from the value `answer`. The compiler gives an error since you can't create a `void` variable.

It seems you want to call the function `printAnswer` with the argument `answer`. The correct syntax for that is:

```
printAnswer(answer);
```